# «basculer» en contexte du cyclisme

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Bonjour,

Je regardais le Tour de France ce matin quand j'ai entendu le verbe «basculer» plusieurs fois et je n'ai pas pu trouver une bonne traduction. Par exemple, la seule phrase complète que je peux me souvenir est «il bascule en tête». Est-ce qu'il y a un sens spécifique de ce verbe dans le cyclisme?

Merci d'avance.

Comment: Ici « basculer » veut dire passer d'une situation donnée à une situation inverse (plus ou moins favorable selon le sens). Ce n'est pas une expression idiomatique et c'est un [usage normal](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basculer) du verbe.. Ce n'est pas un usage spécifique au cyclisme ni même au sport, même si bien sûr on emploie souvent ce verbe dans le langage du sport quand on suit les classements. Tu parles de traduction sans dire quelle langue, en anglais on dirait, par exemple,  *Michael Woods swings into  the lead*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, l'anglais marche pour moi. Les seules traductions que je trouvais étaient des mots comme «toggle» et «topple». Alors il me semblais que l'utilisation était idiomatique ou spécifique au cyclisme...

Comment: [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/il%20bascule%20en%20t%C3%AAte) is probably the best online translator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ici *basculer* veut dire :

> Passer brusquement (dans une situation nouvelle, à une autre position). <sup>1</sup>

> Passer d'une situation, d'une position données à la situation, à la position contraire.<sup>2</sup>

Ce n'est pas une expression idiomatique et c'est un usage normal du verbe. Ce n'est pas non plus un usage spécifique au cyclisme ni même au sport, même si bien sûr on emploie souvent ce verbe dans le langage du sport dans la mesure où il existe des classements.

> L'Italie bascule en tête à la pause, malgré la réduction du score de Romelu Lukaku sur penalty juste avant la mi-temps (1-2).([Le Parisien, 02/07/2021](https://www.leparisien.fr/sports/football/direct-euro-2021-suivez-le-quart-de-finale-choc-entre-la-belgique-et-litalie-02-07-2021-RUBM3M5O2VEE5BR7GZQG2VW4AE.php))

Ci-dessous, d'autres exemple de l'emploi du verbe hors du champ sportif.

> Comment Philippe a basculé dans le camp Macron.<sup>3</sup>

> Le Sénat ayant basculé dans le camp démocrate, Joe Biden se retrouve les mains libres.<sup>4</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>  *Dictionaire culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey)

<sup><sup>2</sup> [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basculer) (I,C)</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> [BFM TV, 17/11/2017](https://www.bfmtv.com/politique/comment-philippe-a-bascule-dans-le-camp-macron_AN-201711170046.html).</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> [*Le Monde*, 07/01/2021](https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2021/01/07/le-senat-ayant-bascule-dans-le-camp-democrate-joe-biden-se-retrouve-les-mains-libres_6065442_3210.html)</sup>